# SSO or Existing (MySQL) user accounts with meteor/telescope

Tags: meteor, telescope

I've poked around docs a bit but haven't figured much out. How would I integrate existing logins (I have these columns: username, password_bc, public_name, email -- it is not a framework/openid/etc, just a CRUDish home login system).

My original thought was making some kind of POST HTTP endpoint in JS with `accounts-password`, restricted to internal IPs and requiring basic auth with a static password to call `Accounts.createUser()` or `Accounts.setPassword` that gets called from my non-JS application backing it -- unless there's some other way I can do this that isn't as seemingly terrible?